# Как сделать редирект всех страниц сайта на другой домен?

Tags: php, .htaccess, сервер, redirect

Как сделать редирект всех страниц сайта (около 5000) на другой домен через .htaccess?
Например, с site.ru на new-site.ru

Comment: А предыдущий вариант какой был? Который описан в заголовке.. чтобы редирект не на аналогичную страницу нового сайта, а только на главную нового сайта?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Подскажите, а он не будет вести на главную?

Comment: @Alex, он будет вести на url, указанный в директиве `RewriteRule`. А вам что требуется?

Comment: Требуется, чтобы главная и внутренние страницы сайта перенаправлялись на аналогичный путь, только на указанном домене. Например, когда человек идет по ссылке site.ru/conacts его перенаправляло на new-site.ru/contacts и тому подобнее. Можно ли это сделать, не указывая каждую страницу вручную массово? Просто, чтобы подменялся домен

Comment: @Alex, внёс правки в свой ответ, попробуйте снова.